# How Scalable is the Google Vision API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I have an IOS app where users can upload images.
I want to run all these images through Google's Vision API.
Could someone please let me know how realistic this idea is?

Let's say that I want to run 1000 images through their API.
How much would this cost me?

In the question title, I used the word scalable because I'm worried that using this service would be really expensive.

This is mainly a question about how much it costs to get Google to scan each an image.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing

Comment: You say you want to "run the images through the API". What are you expecting to get out of this processing? Safe search detection? Figure out what it is? A combination of things?

Comment: I want to detect items in the image. Sorry I was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what you want as a result, but in general, the first 1000 images are free per month. After that it is $1.50 per 1000 images per activity in a month (a few things are more expensive).

So if you wanted to get what labels are in an image (broadly speaking - what is the primary thing this is a picture of, which it sounds like you want), the first 1000 images in a month are free, and the next 1000 would be $1.50. Another 1000 (for a total of 3000) would be another $1.50 for a total of $3 for the 3000.

If, however, you wanted to both get what labels are in an image *and* if there is any explicit content in the image (Safe Search detection), the first 1000 images would be free, but the next 1000 would be $3.00 ($1.50 for the label detection, and $1.50 for the safe search detection).

See [Google Cloud Vision API Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing) for the different types of operations available and the price for each.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comments on the post, I found that the first 1000 monthly requests are free, and the next million cost $1.50 per 1000 requests (for label recognition, which is what I wanted)

There is different pricing for different features.

@SLaks pointed me to the following helpful link https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pricing

Thanks for your help guys!